# How to keep a ruby script running persistently within a Rails app on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have a Mailman server script that checks for incoming email and loads it into the rails app database. The script (should) run continuously and checks for new email every 60 seconds. I was able to run the script on Heroku using `heroku run:detached script/mailman_server`, but when I checked back a few days later it wasn't running. How can I ensure it is always running?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the Cedar stack, and add a Procfile. Eg. Something like...

```
web: bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./unicorn.rb
mailman: bundle exec script/mailman_server
```

Then:

```
heroku ps:scale mailman=1
```

On the command line will add one worker. However. Should the worker encounter some kind of error and close you would need additional config to restart it.

Comment: Thanks stef I'll research your instructions. Is there any way to accomplish this without a worker/on the free Heroku account?

Comment: Afraid not - you'll always be charged for any porcess running as a background task / worker afaik

Comment: Anyone able to point me in the right direction of the "additional config needed to restart" the worker if it encounters an error?

Answer (score 1):

Sendgrid have a service which can accept incoming emails for your app:

http://docs.sendgrid.com/documentation/api/parse-api-2/

I haven't looked at the pricing.

Comment: Another similar service is cloudmailin.com.

Comment: I haven't tried it myself, but [Mailgun should also be an option](http://blog.mailgun.com/post/handle-incoming-emails-like-a-pro-mailgun-api-2-0/).